# Using delimiters to separate multiple parts of a single line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I have a data packet: `s12*0234*e30#r54~s12*0234*e30#r54`, the `~` separates one packet of data.

I have used the following code to separate each packet:

```
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("2.txt")).useDelimiter("~");
```

Now I need to separate "s12","0234"..(all the data).

I tried this code to do that:

```
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("2.txt")).useDelimiter("*#~");
```

Ultimately I have to put it into a database .

Comment: You have to actually _use_ the first Scanner, read the next String, then make your second Scanner around _that_ String and _not the file_ a second time.  Or just use a regex.

Comment: oh.ok i thought about that.so should i store the result in a variable and use that variable the second time to separate again?

Comment: Yes try that out and see if that works, you are going to need to use a loop

Comment: This is conceptually almost identical to "Comma Separated Value" (CSV) format.  If you Google for that you will get lots of ideas.  Also, the concept is similar to JSON, which is a standard way of representing data values in a data packet or text string.  Using some standard scheme is probably advised vs rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can read with the first Scanner the file and transfer this to String. 
Then use Split() to cut this String, you can repeat this Split() function if is necessary.
Finally you have a array of String with all separated by "tokens" and then you can use a (for or while) loop to save this data on a database.